# Identify debugging in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, release-mode

I have an interesting problem.

Is it possible to identify if an assembly is running in Visual Studio?

Look at the following code.

```
if(FoundThatYouAreDebuggingInVisualStudio)
{
    Print "Hello"
} 
else 
{
    Print "Hi"
}
```

The above code is present in a .NET assembly (say XYZ) which is built in Release mode. The user is debugging his/her application (say ABC) that references to XYZ assembly.

I need to identify if the user is debugging in the Visual Studio or he is just running the ABC application.

Any ideas?

-D

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug messages do not get written in release mode so this would be an indication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx)